# Python: How to Set Dummies for a list of Categorical Variables using Looping Code

Tags: python, loops, set, categories

Let's say I have a list of non-binary Categorical Variables that I want to dummify.

Below is the list of categorical variables I have in my dataframe: Rating, Source, Type, State, etc.

Currently, I am manually dummifying each variable with the code below and adding it to the existing dataframe (df_NumTarget_pred_2) shown below.  Is there a way to do this not so manually?

For example, I want to go through every variable in my list and automatically dummify it, delete the original field, and add it to the existing dataframe.

```
    df_R = pd.get_dummies(df_NumTarget_pred_2['Rating'])

    df_NumTarget_pred_2 = pd.concat([df_NumTarget_pred_2, df_R], axis=1)

    del df_NumTarget_pred_2['Rating']

    df_NumTarget_pred_2.shape

    df_NumTarget_pred_2.head()
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The get_dummies can get dummies for multiple columns at once, and drop the original columns if you want.

```
df_final = pd.get_dummies(df_NumTarget_pred_2, 
                          columns=['Rating', 'Source', 'Type', 'State'], 
                          drop_first=True)
```

Comment: ah that worked! thank you :)  Out of curiosity, what does the drop_first do?

Comment: drop_first drops the columns after making them dummy variables.